# Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

i'm developping a webapp using SS for role managing. when i try to log in as admin it works fine,but the problem is when i want to log in as user it does too, which something i don't want to be. any ideas plz

this is my security-cpntext.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- We will be defining all security related configurations in this file -->
<http pattern="/login" security="none" />

<http use-expressions="true" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />  
        <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('Admin')"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/login"/> <!-- We will just use the built-in form login page in Spring -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login" />
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>  --><!--   this means all URL in this app will be checked if user is authenticated -->
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index"/> <!-- the logout url we will use in JSP -->
</http>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" ></beans:property>

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two potential issues here that may be causing the problem.

1) You're specifying `hasRole('Admin')` for `/index`. If the role name is called `Admin` then you should specify `hasRole('ROLE_Admin')`.

2) You've got duplication in your configuration. The `<authentication-manager>` tells Spring security to create a `ProviderManager` instance. So you've declared this, but you've also manually specified the `ProviderManager` as a bean instance duplicating what `<authentication-manager>` does. Remove the following:

```
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" ></beans:property>

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

And leave:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Try that and see what you get.